# Cucumber step now not being found when using a choice of words in step

Tags: visual-studio-code, cucumber, wdio

I have the following in a step "Given('I am logged in/as {string}')". This works and the test passes using either of the options in or as. It is however being flagged with the "Unable to find step for" error.

Previously no error was being displayed for this but has all of a sudden appeared. I am using cucumber in a wdio project and have not made any changes in this area in a while.

Comment: Did you update the cucumber version and/or whatever plugin you are using by any chance?

Comment: @Marit no I didn't but had a vscode update

Comment: Then it looks like the new vscode version is no longer recognising the steps.

Comment: @Marit it does recognise the steps and the code executes. The issue is that it is flagging the steps as undefined. Which makes others think that no step has not been created. I am looking for a way in which it will remove the indicator informing the user that the step has not been defined.

Comment: This seems like an issue with vscode flagging the steps as undefined even when they are not. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with vscode so I can't help you there. You might want to tag this question with relevant vscode labels so vscode users can help you